# Getting less calculated area after merging/dissolving polygons

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, area

After I merge/dissolve polygons together, the area I calculated using the field calculator seems to decrease, in comparison to the calculation of each individual area and then summing it up.
Can somebody tell me why this is happening?
I am using the same projection (Europe equal distant EPSG: 102031) and the same method $area in the field calculator.

Comment: Hi Rahma, do some of your polygons overlap?

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: Hi ! Thank you very much !! Yes, you were right I had overlapping polygones

Comment: I am using QGis.